# Does a Python object which doesn't override comparison operators equals itself?

Tags: python, equality

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

x = A(1)
y = A(2)

q = [x, y]
q.remove(y)
```

I want to remove from the list a specific object which was added before to it and to which I still have a reference. I do not want an equality test. I want an identity test. This code seems to work in both CPython and IronPython, but does the language guarantee this behavior or is it just a fluke?

The `list.remove` method documentation is this: `same as del s[s.index(x)]`, which implies that an equality test is performed.

So will an object be equal to itself if you don't override `__cmp__`, `__eq__` or `__ne__`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**.  In your example `q.remove(y)` would remove the first occurrence of an object which compares equal with `y`.  However, the way the class `A` is defined, you shouldn't<sup>†</sup> ever have a variable compare equal with `y` - with the exception of any other names which are also bound to the same `y` instance.

The relevant section of the docs is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__):

> If no `__cmp__(), __eq__() or __ne__()` operation is defined, class
>   instances are compared by object identity ("address").

So comparison for `A` instances is by identity (implemented as memory address in CPython).  No other object can have an identity equal to `id(y)` within `y`'s lifetime, i.e. for *as long as you hold a reference to `y`* (which you must, if you're going to remove it from a list!)

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Technically, it is still possible to have objects at other memory locations which are comparing equal - `mock.ANY` is one such example.  But these objects need to override their comparison operators to force the result.</sub>

Comment: Interestingly, the behaviour seems to be the opposite in Python 3

Comment: `__cmp__` is [gone in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons).  You can achieve the same effect using `__eq__`, though.

Comment: I was wondering if there is no defined __eq__, does Python 3 compare by address?

Comment: Yes, because it falls back to `object.__eq__` which is implemented with an address-based comparison.

Answer (score 2):

In python, by default an object is always equal to itself (the only exception I can think of is `float("nan")`.  An object of a user-defined class will not be equal to any other object unless you define a comparison function.

See also http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes and no.

Consider the following example

```
>>> class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value        
>>> x = A(1)
>>> y = A(2)
>>> z = A(3)
>>> w = A(3)
>>> q = [x, y,z]
>>> id(y) #Second element in the list and y has the same reference
46167248
>>> id(q[1]) #Second element in the list and y has the same reference
46167248
>>> q.remove(y) #So it just compares the id and removes it
>>> q
[<__main__.A object at 0x02C19AB0>, <__main__.A object at 0x02C19B50>]
>>> q.remove(w) #Fails because though z and w contain the same value yet they are different object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    q.remove(w)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

It will remove from the list iff they are the same object. If they are different object with same value it won;t remove it.

Comment: The answer is simply yes, it's not "yes and no".  And the OP explicitly said they wanted an identity test, not an equality test.