# What does Python double equal sign do for object without eq implemented

Tags: python, equality

This is a really basic Python question but I can't find a quick answer. Say I have

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node1 == node2 # False
node1.__eq__(node2) # NotImplemented
```

I've read that `NotImplemented` is truthy, so now we have

```
if node1.__eq__(node2):
    print('yes') # prints 'yes'

if node1 == node2:
    print('yes') # does not print
```

Could you please explain what `==` does here? Does it call `is` or something since `node1 == node1` is True.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588890/does-a-python-object-which-doesnt-override-comparison-operators-equals-itself

Comment: That question is a much less straightforward way to ask this very question though. Seems the answer is in the accepted answer's comment: it falls back to `object.__eq__`