# Removing item from a stored list in pickleDB throws: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, pickle

I have a `Message` class:

```
messages = []

class Message:
   id = 1
   content = "m1"

   def __init__(self, id, content):
      self.id = id
      self.content = content
```

Following code works as expected:

```
m1 = Message(1, "m1")
m2 = Message(2, "m2")

messages.append(m1)
messages.append(m2)
messages.remove(m2) #Works as expected
```

But when I load `messages` from a pickleDB and try to remove the item, it throws this error:

> list.remove(x): x not in list

```
def save_database():
   with open("database.db", 'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump(messages, f)

def load_database():
   global messages
   with open("database.db", 'rb') as f:
      messages = pickle.load(f)

def add_message(msg):
  load_database()
  messages.append(msg)
  save_database()


m1 = Message(1, "m1")
m2 = Message(2, "m2")

add_message(m1)
add_message(m2)

load_database()
messages.remove(m2) #ERROR: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the objects that are read from the pickle dump are not the same as those in your program ([`pickle.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler.load) creates new objects).

Hence, when [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) looks for the object in the list, it won't find it and instead raises an exception.

See also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8588993/14722562) which discusses how equality is defined on objects in Python by default.

You need to override the way equality is checked, by implementing a custom [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method in your `Message` class:

```
class Message:

    def __init__(self, id, content):
        self.id = id
        self.content = content

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Message):
            return self.id == other.id and self.content == other.content
        return False
```

The general approach is to first check whether the object being compared is of the right type. If it is, then compare the relevant fields.

## How do I handle this if I don't own the class?

You could subclass it, and then override `__eq__`. Though in such a case, you may need to consider how `super().__eq__` behaves as well.

### Subclass that overrides __eq__ completely:

In this version, we discard the superclass's `__eq__` completely and implement our own logic for checking equality.

```
class MyMessage(Message):

    def __init__(self, id, content, extra):
        super().__init__(id, content)
        self.extra = extra

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # As an example, we only check `extra`, and ignore everything else
        if isinstance(other, MyMessage):
            return self.extra == other.extra
        return False
```

### Subclass that overrides and takes super().__eq__ into account:

In this version, we call the superclass's `__eq__` and add our own logic for checking equality in addition to it.

```
class MyMessage2(Message):

    def __init__(self, id, content, extra):
        super().__init__(id, content)
        self.extra = extra

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyMessage2):
            ret = super().__eq__(other)
            if not ret:
                return False
            return self.extra == other.extra
        return False
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I do, if `Message` class doesn't belong to me? (for example `Message` class in `telethon` library.)

Comment: You could subclass it (e.g. `class MyMessage(Message)`), and then still override `__eq__`. Though in such a case, you may need to consider how `super().__eq__` behaves as well.